# Evento previo al cierre de aplicación Android

Tags: android, android-studio

En una aplicación tengo una actividad principal y varios fragments, el aplicativo funciona conectándose a dos dispositivos bluetooth.

Lo que necesito es que antes de cerrar LA APLICACIÓN se desconecte y apague el bluetooth del movil. He probado con los métodos onDestoy() y onPause() dentro del MainActivity pero no tengo los resultados esperados pues si bien el blue se apaga el aplicativo se hace inestable y se genera excepciones y no puede salir normalmente.

Alguien me puede guiar con el método sobre el cual debo programar. Muchas gracias.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Recalco el problema no son las lineas de código, pues si apagan el bluetooth, sino es el evento dentro de cual lo hago el que genera excepciones no deseadas.

Comment: puedes compartir la exception que sale en el logcat? agrega ex.printStackTrace(); en tu catch, y nos lo compartes

Comment: La excepción se refiere a que la aplicación necesita usar los dispositivos pero estos perdieron conexión, en especial cuando lo pongo en el metodo onPause().Muchas gracias

Comment: @Kevtho podrías agregar tu código completo, agregue una respuesta, comentame resultados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revisa esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039807/250260) de [@BradHein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268803/brad-hein), primeramente debes cerrar los streams y las conexiones abiertas y despues el BluetoothAdapter/BluetoothManager :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        resetConnection();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { //comprueba esta habilitado.
              mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); //Deshabilita.
        }
        //mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

método `resetConnection()` :

```
private void resetConnection() {
        if (mBTInputStream != null) {
                try {mBTInputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
                mBTInputStream = null;
        }

        if (mBTOutputStream != null) {
                try {mBTOutputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
                mBTOutputStream = null;
        }

        if (mBTSocket != null) {
                try {mBTSocket.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
                mBTSocket = null;
        }

}
```

Revisa el ciclo de vida de la `Activity` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen apunte... ;)

Comment: genial esta es una buena idea

Answer (score 1):

El método que debes elegir depende del comportameinto que estés esperando de tu aplicación. Si quieres desactivar el Bluetooth cuando otra aplicación se ponga en primer plano (el usuario cambia de tarea, por ejemplo), debieras utilizar los métodos `onResume()` y `onPause()`.

[image: Ciclo de vida de una Activity]

Si lo que quieres es desactivar el BT cuando tu aplicación se destruya del todo, entonces `onDestroy()`.

En cuanto a los errores que estás recibiendo, te sugiero que apliques el siguiente criterio a la hora de llamar a los métodos de la clase `super`.

- Cuando sobreescribes un **método que *crea*** tu aplicación (onCreate, onResume, etc.) debieras llamar primero al método de la clase padre (con `super.onResume()`).
- Cuando sobreescribes un **método que *destruye*** tu aplicación (onDestroy, onPause, etc.), llama al método de la clase padre al final (`super.onPause()`)

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    // Primero llamo al sistema 
    super.onResume();

    // Aquí hago mi trabajo
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    // Aquí libero mis recursos, 
    // En concreto desactivo el Bluetooth

    // Y ahora llamo a la clase padre
    super.onPause();
}
```

Tómalo por favor como una regla general, pues siempre existen excepciones.

Comment: El uso de onDestroy u onPause es correcto, el OP tiene problema al tratar de "desconectar" el BluetoothAdapter.

Comment: Es frecuente ver excepciones y errores tras salir de la aplicación, debido a que una llamada a `super.onDestroy()` prematura libera los recursos que más tarde el usuario utiliza en el método sobreescrito. De hecho, @Kevtho comenta que **si** se apaga, pero que se producen errores.