# ¿Como detener un servicio al salir de la aplicación en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, servicio

Estoy desarrollando un juego, y este posee musica. La musica la estoy ejecutando mediante un servicio.
Lo que quiero es que al salir de la aplicacion, osea volver a mi escritorio del dispositivo el servicio se detenga. Dejo el codigo del servicio.

```
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.IBinder;


    public class SoundManager extends Service {
        static boolean reproducir=true;
        static boolean reproducir_musica=true;
        static boolean reproducir_musica2=true;
        private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        player=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musica);
        player.setLooping(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid){
        player.start();
    }


}
```

Y en el Manifest solo tengo esto:

```
<service android:name=".SoundManager" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, fíjate que no pegaste el código del Manifest, edita la pregunta! :)

Comment: Ya lo edite....

Comment: Luego de leer tu pregunta esto es lo que puedo deducir, si solo quieres que se reproduzca la música cuando estés en determinada Activity puedes crear un subproceso nuevo en lugar de un servicio, comenzar a ejecutarlo con `onStart()` y luego detenerlo con `onStop()`. Por otro lado si buscas detener un servicio puedes hacerlo con `stopSelf()` o `stopService()`, cuando tu desees. Espero que te sea de ayuda y que haya entendido tu pregunta, puedes encontrar mas información en la documentación oficial de [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es-419).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me guio bastante, pero quisiera saber como detengo el servicio al salir de la aplicacion, osea, estando desde cualquier activity y por ejemplo apretar el boton de "home" de mi dispositivo se detenga el servicio

Comment: mira esta pregunta que hizo otra persona anteriormente, parece ser parecido a lo que pides. 
[Evento previo al cierre de aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42549/evento-previo-al-cierre-de-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android)
Suerte :)